# Trail mode of hovering events doesnt work in tsParticles(similar to particlejs)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, particles.js

I have got two queries, I am implementing tsParticles in my React application.
**First one:.**

```
<Particles 
        id="tsparticles"
        options={{
          background: {
            color: {
              value: "black",
            },
          },
          fpsLimit: 60,
          interactivity: {
            detectsOn: "window",
            events: {
              onClick: {
                enable: true,
                mode: "push",
              },
              onHover: {
                
                enable: true,
                mode: "trail",
              },
              resize: true,
            },
            modes: {
              bubble: {
                distance: 400,
                duration: 2,
                opacity: 0.8,
                size: 40,
              },
              push: {
                quantity: 4,
              },
              repulse: {
                distance: 200,
                duration: 0.4,
              },
            },
          },
          particles: {
              
            color:{
                animation:{
                    enable:true,
                    speed:50,
                },
                value:"#f00"
            },
            links: {
                shadow:{
                    blur:true,
                    color:"#00ff00"

                },
                triangles:{
                    frequency: 1
                },
              color: "random",
              distance: 150,
              enable: true,
              frequency:1,
              opacity: 0.5,
              width: 1,
            },
            collisions: {
              enable: true,
            },
            move: {
                angle:{
                    offset: 45,
                    value: 90
                },
                attract:{
                    rotate:{
                        x:3000,
                        y:3000
                    }
                },
                gravity:{
                    acceleration: 9.81,
                    enable:false,
                    maxSpeed:1
                },
              direction: "none",
              enable: true,
              outMode: "bounce",
              random: false,
              speed: 6,
              straight: false,
            },
            number: {
              density: {
                enable: true,
                value_area: 1000,
              },
              value: 80,
            },
            opacity: {
              value: 0.5,
            },
            shape: {
              type: "circle",
            },
            size: {
              random: true,
              value: 5,
            },
          },
          detectRetina: true,
        }}
      />
```

There is a section of onHover and key value of mode in it. There are like 8 different modes to it, can be viewed in [https://particles.matteobruni.it/](https://tsparticles.matteobruni.it/) .
All other modes work fine but the trail mode when I use this code, am I missing some other properties to the Particles component?

**Second one:**
Also,
I have got two divs, one for the particle and the other for the text to display on top of it. I have achieved this using z-index and positions.

I need the canvas height to be dynamic that is occupy 100% height of its parent whatever the screen size is. I have tried doing this by including Particles component inside a div and keeping its height to 100% but the canvas height decreases with the decrease in the screen size.

Kindly help me, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, there's a lot to answer here, but I try to do my best.

## First point, the config and mouse trail

The mouse trail needs more configuration, in the `modes` section of `interactivity` you have to configure the `trail` section.

You can see a sample here: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/abdpbBY

If you need more documentation checkout the right section in documentation: https://particles.js.org/interfaces/_options_interfaces_interactivity_modes_itrail_.itrail.html

## Second point, the canvas size

If you need a dynamic canvas size the best solution is to use the `backgroundMode` in the options root object

You can see a sample here: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/MWeqxNL

The background mode if enabled sets the `canvas` style with a `fixed` position and the desired `zIndex`

You can see the documentation here: https://particles.js.org/interfaces/_options_interfaces_backgroundmode_ibackgroundmode_.ibackgroundmode.html

If you are using the `backgroundMode`, the better results are obtained without setting any style to the containing `div` (the tsParticles target/container)